# Colorama tool on looping through a list- not working in terminal (Python)

Tags: python, list, colorama

### I am unable to get a coloured output on the following:

```
Letters= ['QWERTYUPOIFSAJKVMPFOQWKFWSPAEOOIUSKFISPLCKSKLJHXIWTSLAVW']
data = (Letters)

from colorama import init

init()
init(convert=True)

from colorama import Fore

Selection1 = ['C','L','D','O','I']
Selection2 = ['K','W','Y']
Selection3 = ['N','V']
Selection4 = ['A','G','D']

for x in data:
    if x in Selection1:
        print (Fore.YELLOW , (x))
    if x in Selection2:
        print (Fore.GREEN, (x))
    if x in Selection3:
        print (Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, (x))
    if x in Selection4:
        print (Fore.BLUE, (x))
    else:
        print(Fore.WHITE , (x))
```

---

### If I change Letters from a list with [] to tuple with (), the output is coloured, but I would prefer to have all the letters as a list in one block rather than individually printed down the page.

Comment: Why `data = (Letters)` ?

Comment: Just use `Letters` without doing `data=(Letters)` directly in your `for` loop

Comment: It was so I could substitute in some different things later. Anyway, that doesn't fix the issue. No colour on the output

Comment: My bad I meant: `for x in Letters[0]` or make `data = Letters[0]` and use `data` in your for loop

Comment: This will also work: `data = list(Letters[0])`

Comment: That works for getting the output coloured, but is there a way of not having the output as a long list and instead in one block letter after letter? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Try: `print(Fore.YELLOW, x, end='')` to not have `\n` printed every letter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same type, make :

```
>>> data = list(Letters[0])
```

To `print` all characters in same line, pass `''` to `end` parameters of `print` method:

```
>>> print(Fore.WHITE, x, end='')
```

Also, your `if-else` block needs fixing, since you are checking for *almost* all your conditions, see below updated code, this way you will be checking only one time for each character:

```
from colorama import init, Fore

init(convert=True)

Letters= ['QWERTYUPOIFSAJKVMPFOQWKFWSPAEOOIUSKFISPLCKSKLJHXIWTSLAVW']
data = list(Letters[0])

Selection1 = ['C','L','D','O','I']
Selection2 = ['K','W','Y']
Selection3 = ['N','V']
Selection4 = ['A','G','D']

for x in data:
    if x in Selection1:
            print(Fore.YELLOW, x, end='')
    elif x in Selection2:
            print(Fore.GREEN, x, end='')
    elif x in Selection3:
            print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, x, end='')
    elif x in Selection4:
            print(Fore.BLUE, x, end='')
    else:
            print(Fore.WHITE, x, end='')
```